# Unable to get the user information in InfoPath form using UserInformation list

Tags: infopath, forms-services, user-information-list

I am having a form and I am trying to get the current user details to be repopulated like first name, lastname, email, phone, etc using the user information list in SharePoint 2010. I did all the steps but when the user trying to add the new item I see all the fields as blank nothing is showing up.

I have created a data connection to User Information list and than on form load I have set fields value UserName() =  UserName() from function fx and than query for data using data connection.

Can anyone help me on this if am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Site Collection to call for user Information  list in InfoPath I have used Site level and it worked.It is populating all the data from the list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use GetUserProfileByName operation of UserProfileService.asmx web service. It has the properties that you need. Add this on Data Connection, this will run on load. Put rules on load to set the fields that you want to be auto populated using the web service.

See this for detailed steps: http://thinketg.com/using-infopath-and-the-web-service-getuserprofilebyname/

Comment: hi Mekalikot I have done with that though but am looking for something on User Information list which SharePoint has. Is there any limitation on that as am not getting data after I publish I could only see the empty form without any pre-populated data .Thanks

Comment: I can also see the data in prievew mode of the form but once I publish I don't see anything its complete blank.Any guess or idea on this .Thanks.

Comment: check if the DATA RETRIEVED is set to Every time form is opened. Then try dragging the folder Property Data(repeating table) into the form then test in preview and published mode.

Comment: Where can I find that option

Comment: select Data Connections on the lower right of the form when in design mode. Select the web service data connection that you created then select modify. Click next until you reached the "renaming of the data connection", there is a tick box there about retrieving date when opened. Check it.

Comment: That doesn't worked in my case as it is throwing error saying "large amount of data cannot be pulled to the form".any idea??

Comment: hmmm, sorry, never experienced that error when using that web service. Are there any other Data Connections that is set to retrieve when open?